# how do i allow a function to be used anywhere in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i have 2 classes and when i run the first one, it works fine but when it gets to the second class i get an error saying `AttributeError: 'Question2' object has no attribute 'correct'`. how do i make it so that the functions work in both of the class? is there something wrong with my indent? please help me fix this code, thanks:
**Edit: i have a problem with using self, if i remove self from the functions it wouldnt work, if i indent it to not be a part of the class, it still wont work, the self gets turns white**

```
class Question1:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        x = random.randint(5, 12)
        y = random.randint(5, 12)
        self.master = master
        self.user_choice = StringVar()
        self.user_choice.set("")
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=200, pady=200)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.q = Label(self.frame, text="What is {} + {} ?".format(x, y))
        self.q.grid(row=0)
        self.ans = Entry(self.frame, width=50, textvariable=self.user_choice)
        self.ans.grid(row=1)
        self.answer = x+y
        self.sub = Button(self.frame, text="submit", command=self.correct)
        self.sub.grid(row=3)

    def correct(self):
        global p
        if int(self.user_choice.get()) == self.answer:
            cor = Label(self.frame,text="Correct!")
            cor.grid(row=5, pady=20)
            p += 1
            if p >= 3:
               Question2(self.master)
            else:
                self.sub.destroy()
                nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", command=self.necs)
                nex.grid(row=4)
        else:
            inc = Label(self.frame,text="incorrect")
            inc.grid(row=5, pady=20)
            self.sub.destroy()
            nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", command=self.necs)
            nex.grid(row=4)
            self.frame.destroy()
            Question1(self.master)

    def necs(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        Question1(self.master)


class Question2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        x = random.randint(2, 2)
        y = random.randint(2, 3)
        self.master = master
        self.user_choice = StringVar()
        self.user_choice.set("")
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=200, pady=200)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.q = Label(self.frame, text="What is {} x {} ?".format(x, y))
        self.q.grid(row=0)
        self.ans = Entry(self.frame, width=50, textvariable=self.user_choice)
        self.ans.grid(row=1)
        self.answer = x * y
        self.sub = Button(self.frame, text="submit", command=self.correct)
        self.sub.grid(row=3)
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by inheriting the properties of Question1 to Question2:
That can be:

```py
class Question2(Question1):
    #you can access that by:
    self.correct()
```

Other way is you can define a global function outside both the classes and you can easily access it.
Example:

```py
#somewhere globally:
def correct():
    #some code

class Question1():
    correct()

class Question2():
    correct()
```

I think you can develop more such ideas of using a function which will be required by multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

As @JenilDave answered, you need to define function outside class, inherit from other class.explicitly call class.

i.e. for last case:

```
class Question1:
    def correct():
        <codes>

class Question2:
    q1 = Question1()
    q1.correct()

    or

    Question1.correct(<Question1 instance>)
```

But since your 'correct' function are heavily dependent to Question1, you can't use either way, and reconstruct your codes.

Working example below:

---

Instead of generating question Class per questions, send lists of questions to one class.

Every time you succeed third time, you'll move on to next questions by poping list you've provided before.

When Lists are empty, pop() causes IndexError and program closes.

...

Since I can't get what variable 'p' stands for, I'm guessing it's number of successes(passes).

Full Code:

```
import random
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Entry, Button, StringVar, Tk


class QuestionFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, question_answer):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.master = master
        self.entries = question_answer
        self.question, self.answer = self.entries.pop(0)

        self.success = 0

        self.user_choice = StringVar()

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()

        self.quest_label = Label(self.frame)
        self.ans = Entry(self.frame, width=50, textvariable=self.user_choice)
        self.sub = Button(self.frame)

        self.quest_label.grid(row=0)
        self.ans.grid(row=1)
        self.sub.grid(row=3)

        self.reload_question()

    def reload_question(self):
        self.x, self.y = random.sample(range(5, 12), 2)

        next_quest = f"What is {self.question.format(self.x, self.y)} ?"

        self.quest_label.configure(text=next_quest)
        self.ans.delete(0, 'end')
        self.sub.configure(text="submit", command=self.correct)

    def next(self):
        print(self.success)
        if self.success == 3:
            # loads next entry
            try:
                self.question, self.answer = self.entries.pop(0)
            except IndexError:
                self.master.destroy()
            else:
                self.success = 0
                self.reload_question()
        else:
            self.reload_question()

    def correct(self):

        self.sub.configure(text="Next", command=self.next)
        if int(self.user_choice.get()) == self.answer(self.x, self.y):
            self.quest_label['text'] = "Correct!"
            self.success += 1

        else:
            self.quest_label['text'] = "Incorrect!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Passing questions with list of (question, answer) tuples.
    tests = [("{} x {}", lambda x, y: x*y),
             ("{} - {}", lambda x, y: x-y)]

    root = Tk()
    root.title(f'Some fancy title')
    window = QuestionFrame(root, tests)
    window.mainloop()
```